# rails form using database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i have a rails form ive made in which the form fields are extracted from the database. i did it like this because for different products, there are different form fields. i could have made one big order form to do it, and if the product field didnt apply to the product it would be left blank, but it seemed like making the fields being called from a database made more sense because there are 30-40 fields per order. anyways the error in which im running into is when im extracting the row `field_type`, it prints out the literal value instead of putting it in rails. heres what it looks like:

```
  <% @form_field.each do |field| %>
    <p>
      <%= "f.#{field.field_type}" %> #this prints out f.text_field
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

Instead of printing out f.text_field, i would like it to actually make a text field. I tried using raw but no look seeing as thats for html. is there a way to do this in rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to build up the string and `send` it to `f`, like `f.send(field.field_type)` (untested) along with any arguments needed for that particular form field type.

Comment: but im not looking to send info, im looking to retrieve infro from the database. if the info in the database says "text_field", i then would like the form to display a text field

Comment: @Thomas And that is how you'd do it: you need to send the method name/symbol to the `f` object.

Comment: ok thank you. do you think it makes more sense to use one big model to accomplish what i need or use many tables?